# get duplicates on union of tabls in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have a table(origin) that contains 3x Email-columns and 3x respective ID-columns.
 I want to create a new table(first_step) by stacking the 3x Email- and the 3x ID-columns over each other, filter for specific values and than only keep the rows that do have duplicates in the final table with a single Email-column and ID-column ("Email", "ID").
I achieved the first part, but got stuck on the count+filter for duplicates -> when trying to create an additional column with e.g. ADDCOLUMNS, DAX does not recognize the created table (first_step)

final_table =

```
    var first_step= 
        UNION(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                origin,
                FILTER(origin,CONTAINSSTRING(origin[Email_1], "@"))),
            "Email", 'origin'[Email_1],
            "ID", origin[ID_1]),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                iBase,
                FILTER(origin, CONTAINSSTRING(origin[Email_2], "@"))),
            "Email", 'origin'[Email_2], 
            "ID", origin[ID_2]),
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                origin,
            FILTER(origin, CONTAINSSTRING(origin[Email_3], "@"))),
            "Email", origin[Email_3], 
            "ID", origin[ID_3])
    )

    var result = 
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            first_step,
            "count",
            COUNT([Email]))


return
result
```

The Error says: Cannot identify the table that contains [Email] column.

How can I solve this in an elegant manner? I dont want to create different tables in my Model for this one task.